# How to draw a rectangle using 4 coordinates?

Tags: flutter

I have a use case in which I've to draw a rectangle using the 4 coordinates. I don't want to use drawLine() as later I need a GestureDetector on the rectangle. How can I draw using drawRect()?

```
canvas.drawLine(
  new Offset(rectLeft, rectBottom - lineWidth / 2),
  new Offset(rectRight, rectBottom - lineWidth / 2),
  rectPaint
); // bottom

canvas.drawLine(
  new Offset(rectLeft, rectTop + lineWidth / 2),
  new Offset(rectRight, rectTop + lineWidth / 2), 
  rectPaint
); // top

canvas.drawLine(
  new Offset(rectLeft + lineWidth / 2, rectBottom),
  new Offset(rectLeft + lineWidth / 2, rectTop), 
  rectPaint
);  //left

canvas.drawLine(
  new Offset(rectRight - lineWidth / 2, rectBottom),
  new Offset(rectRight - lineWidth / 2, rectTop), 
  rectPaint
);  //right
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a look at the official documentation. You can draw rect in a number of ways. https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Rect-class.html If you have already looked into it and you're missing something or you need something different, please mention it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a CustomPainter

```
class YourRect extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawRect(
      new Rect.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 50.0),
      new Paint()..color = new Color(0xFF0099FF),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(YourRect oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

then use it like this:

```
new GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    debugPrint("hello");
  },
  child: Container(
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    child: CustomPaint(
      painter: (YourdrawRect()),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use create a polygon and use `drawPath()` function of the `canvas`

```
canvas.drawPath(
    Path()..addPolygon([
      Offset(0, 0),
      Offset(10, 0),
      Offset(10, 10),
      Offset(0, 10),
    ], true),
    paint);
```